# make sure first three digits of phone number are not 0's, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a phone number with javascript and I'm stuck  at this part

The area code (first 3 numbers in 999) can't be all zeros (0)'s

I know the code to make which ever format i want (say xxx-xxx-xxxx) but how do I make sure the first 0 arent all zeroes?

any help is appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: `var isValid = !/^000/.test(str);`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in many ways, here's a few examples using different methods.

**Using startsWith**

```
 var num = "000-xxx-xxxx";

 if (num.startsWith("000") === true) {
      console.log("Number starts with 000");
 }
```

**Using substr**

```
 var num = "000-xxx-xxxx";
 var first_three = num.substr(0, 3);

 if (first_three === "000") {
      console.log("Number starts with 000");
 }
```

**Using split**

```
 var num = "000-xxx-xxxx";
 var first_three = num.split("-")[0];

 if (first_three === "000") {
      console.log("Number starts with 000");
 }
```

**Using a regular expression**

```
 var num = "000-xxx-xxxx";

 if (/^000/.test(num)) {
      console.log("Number starts with 000");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt`, it will ignore everything after the first non-numeric character in the string:

```js
var phone1 = '000-555-4444';
var phone2 = '555-555-5555';

function isValidAreaCode(phoneNumber) {
   return parseInt(phoneNumber, 10) > 0;
}

console.log(phone1, 'valid?', isValidAreaCode(phone1));
console.log(phone2, 'valid?', isValidAreaCode(phone2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^[0]{3}$` or `^\d{3}$`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are testing American area codes, using the regular expression
`/^[2-9][0-8][0-9]/` to test them should work. [According to
this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan#Area_code).
Areacodes can start with a number between 2 and 9, the second number can be any
number except 9 and the last number can be any number.

```
function hasValidAreaCode(num) {
  var stripped = num.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove any no-numeric characters
  return /^[2-9][0-8][0-9]/.test(stripped);
}
```

Interactive example:

```js
function hasValidAreaCode(num) {
  var stripped = num.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove any no-numeric characters
  return /^[2-9][0-8][0-9]/.test(stripped);
}

var elPhonenumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber');
elPhonenumber.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

  var v = elPhonenumber.value;
  if (v.replace(/\D/g, '').length > 2) {
    var valid = hasValidAreaCode(v);
    if (valid) {
      elPhonenumber.classList.add('valid');
      elPhonenumber.classList.remove('invalid');
    } else {
      elPhonenumber.classList.remove('valid');
      elPhonenumber.classList.add('invalid');
    }
  } else {
    elPhonenumber.classList.remove('valid', 'invalid');
  }
 });
```

```css
.valid, .invalid {
  color: #000;
}
.valid {
  color: green;
}
.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="phonenumber">Please enter a phonenumber</label> <input id="phonenumber">
```